# C++ : anti-aliased points overlapping (alpha blend)

Tags: c++, pixel, alpha, antialiasing

I couldn't find a precise answer to this issue after looking around here and Googling. I've got a small piece of code that is plotting points to a float array that represents an image. I came across Xiaolin Wu's anti-aliasing from another post somewhere else (http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_wupixl.htm). This all makes sense and I have it working, however it doesn't explain how to handle cases where two particles (or Wu pixels) overlap or share the same pixels...

I have tried creating another buffer (samples per pixel) and adding each particle's contribution to that and then averaging all the values after all points have been plotted, but it doesn't really give results I expected (the brightness seems halved, funny overlapping between points, etc.).

My question is, how is this kind of case typically handled? Since it's anti-aliased, no particle has a 100% contribution to a pixel (well... very rarely) so it can't be a matter of just swapping the old pixel value for the new value.

Any tips would be much appreciated! Hope this is clear and a valid question...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found some info about basic alpha blending. Seems to do the trick!

new = (color * alpha) + (old * (1.0 - alpha));

Good enough for now.